# RESTful design - requesting multiple records by passing a list

Tags: c#, rest, design-patterns, asp.net-web-api, restful-architecture

I am currently writing a RESTful service for a client who wants to pull stock records (free stock quantity) out of there accounts system and display them on the web.

I have the current endpoints :

GET /stockitems - returns free stock for all stock items

GET /stockitems/STOCKCODE - returns a single free stock record for the STOCKCODE

The requirements from the customer states *"It will be possible to return the details of specific stock items only by passing in a list of stock codes."*

How would I accomplish this in a RESTful way? Is it even possible?

Comment: Possibly a good job for OData and [$filter](http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/odata/v4.0/errata01/os/complete/part2-url-conventions/odata-v4.0-errata01-os-part2-url-conventions-complete.html#_Toc395267111)

Comment: I have to get the data from an accounting system using there basic API so i can't utilize OData

Comment: If you don't have any control over the API, then what are you asking? @ChrisBint has the only two possible solutions, with the third being "change the API".

Comment: I can manually query the API, the question is based on the design of the restful service to make sure i comply with the principles of restful design

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could call the GET /stockitems and filter accordingly at the consumer.

or

You could call the GET /stockitems/STOCKCODE  for each product code.

Comment: I guess i could create a manual filter i.e. GET /stockitem?code='stockcode1, stockcode2, stockcode3'